# Difference between these sentences?

Tags: tense, verbs

When she left, she realized that she ate his snack

When she left, she realized that she was eating his snack

I am writing about a situation where she already ate his snack before she realized what she did and I am not sure which sentence would be correct. I would also appreciate if you could tell me the difference.

Comment: If the snack is *completely* eaten (she's not *still* eating it), the most likely phrasing would be *...she realized that she **had eaten** his snack*. The Past Continuous version *(**was eating**)* is only suitable if your "narrative time" (the time that you're talking about, *when* things were happening) falls somewhere between when she started eating it, and when she finished.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two sentences is that while the first describes a discrete (past perfect) act of eating, the second describes a continuous (imperfect) act of eating.

However, a better way write what I believe you're trying to communicate would be, `When she left, she realized that she had eaten his snack.`

This is an example of the pluperfect past tense.  It's appropriate here because we're trying to describe a time in the past (when she left) at which time she realized something about a time deeper in the past (when she ate the apple).

Answer (score 1):

The simple past (*she ate his snack*) is a backshifted version of the simple present (*she eats his snack*), which is rarely used for most verbs except for a habitual or timeless sense.

So what you want is either a backshifted version of

> *She is eating his snack* => *She was eating his snack*

or of

> *She has eaten his snack* => *She had eaten his snack*.

depending on the meaning you want.

(*She ate his snack* is also possible for the "present" version, though I think less likely, and that would also backshift to *She had eaten his snack*. The past perfect serves as a backshifted version of both the past and the present perfect).